# How to use fastify to send multiple URL parameters?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, fastify

I have declared route using fastify as follows:

```
const apiService = require('./apiService');

try {
    server.get('/api/status/*', apiService);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

My api service is defined as follows:

```js
async function entryFunc(request, response) {
    try {
        console.log("Params are ");
        console.log(request.params);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I am getting following output when calling api `http://localhost:3002/api/status/1/2`:

```
Params are:
{ '*': '1/2' }
```

The url can have `infinite number of parth params` and that is why I am using `wildcard` in my route

I want to modify `entryFunc(request, response)` such that the values `1` and `2` are stored in an array and when I print `array[0]` I should get value as `1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fasify uses [`find-my-way`](https://github.com/delvedor/find-my-way/#supported-path-formats) as the router and supports all that functions.

If you have always 2 path params you should define your route as:

```
server.get('/api/status/:one/:two', apiService);
```

And then your `params` will be like:

```
// /api/status/hello/world
{
  "one": "hello",
  "two": "world"
}
```

That you can convert to an array simply by `Object.values(request.params) // ["hello", "world"]` or `request.params['*'].split('/')`

Comment: The url can have infinite number of parth params and that is why I am using wildcard in my route

Comment: I am getting `[ '1/2' ]` when using `Object.values(request.params)`. How to convert it into an array as `['1','2']` ??

Comment: `request.params['*'].split('/')`

Comment: What about the situation of `/api/status/:one&:two` ? How would that work ?

Comment: What do you mean?